# How can I pass menu below?Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/

This is code for menu:

```
 <header id="masthead" class="navbar navbar-default" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="" role="navigation">
<!--            <div class="container-fluid">-->
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">

                <!--            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">-->
                <!--                <div class="form-group">-->
                <!--                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">-->
                <!--                </div>-->
                <!--                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>-->
                <!--            </form>-->

                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'zdwpbs' ); ?></a>
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ,
                                    'menu_class' => 'nav-menu') );
                ?>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
<!--            </div>-->
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</header>
```

I what when everything width = 1200px menu below to go.
Currently going on all menu items below.

I want to stay all in line elements but to go below

I put a picture to better understand what I mean.
http://i58.tinypic.com/35bbf9h.jpg

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can u share the rendered html code rather than the server code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add custom media css in you css code. As a know to see your code.
Put this and

**I hope it will helps you**.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 768px){
    .collapse.navbar-collapse ,.navbar-header{float: none;}
    .menu-menu-container ul{padding:10px 0;}
    .menu-menu-container ul:after{content: '';display: block;clear:both;}
    .menu-menu-container ul li{padding:0 50px 0 0;} 
}
```

*you should customize this according you need.*

Comment: I tried to add this code but does not work.
I have to do something special?
I think not find class-menu .menu

Comment: Can you please show your code in http://www.bootply.com/new for better understanding.

Comment: Add this in bottom of your `style.css`

Comment: Thank you very much
I have one thing to ask you, can you explain me what each line of code refers?

Comment: I am just inherit you existing class in size between `1200px` and `768px` using media queries.